# My Python code is looping at the wrong place

Tags: python, loops

I have written this code for an assignment and it not working as it should. I want my program to validate user input for 3 users when they enter the names and grades for 3 test. my program just check the first input and then asks for the other user name and skips asking the user for an input or validating the input.

```
validInput1 = False 
validInput2 = False 
validInput3 = False
studentnames = [] 
studentMarkTest1 = [] 
studentMarkTest2 = []
studentMarkTest3 = [] 
totalScores = [] 
sum = 0 
for i in range(3):
    sname = input("Enter Student name:")
    while not validInput1:
        score1 = int(input("What did {} get on their test 1?".format(sname)))
        if score1 < 0 or score1 >20:
          print("Invalid input")
        else:
          validInput1 = True
    while not validInput2:
        score2 = int(input("What did {} get on their test 2?".format(sname)))
        if score2 < 0 or score2 >25:
          print("Invalid input")
        else:
          validInput2 = True
    while not validInput3:
        score3 = int(input("What did {} get on their test 3?".format(sname)))
        if score3 < 0 or score3 >35:
          print("Invalid input")
        else:
          validInput3 = True
    totalScore = score1+ score2+ score3
    sum = sum + totalScore
    AverageTestScore = sum / 3
    # saving name and grade
    studentnames.append(sname)
    studentMarkTest1.append(score1)
    studentMarkTest2.append(score2)
    studentMarkTest3.append(score3)
    totalScores.append(totalScore) for i in range(3):
    print(studentnames[i],"total Test score",totalScores[i]) print("class average", AverageTestScore)
```

here what happens when i run the program

```
>>> 
Enter Student name:g
What did g get on their test 1?44
Invalid input
What did g get on their test 1?33
Invalid input
What did g get on their test 1?44
Invalid input
What did g get on their test 1?22
Invalid input
What did g get on their test 1?20
What did g get on their test 2?34
Invalid input
What did g get on their test 2?23
What did g get on their test 3?55
Invalid input
What did g get on their test 3?44
Invalid input
What did g get on their test 3?32
Enter Student name:e
Enter Student name:e
g total Test score 75
e total Test score 75
e total Test score 75
class average 75.0
>>>
```

How can I get the highest test score value stored in totalscore and then print out the highest score with the name of the student with the highest score?

Comment: Please copy and paste the code and output from your application directly; it's currently impossible to read your code (because it's impossible to tell how indented each line is)

Comment: Your code is not readable at all. use 4 space for each line and resubmit.

Comment: images are even worse than unformatted code ...

Comment: You should use `raw_input` instead of `input`.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach im pretty sure hes using python3 ...

Comment: Pro-tips: keep your questions free of chat and just concentrate on the question material itself. With titles this is especially the case - long Reddit-style titles don't do well here. Bear in mind also that volunteers don't take too well to deadline mentions, since they are here out of kindness and at their own leisure.

Comment: With that in mind, please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its easy to get confused when you have a big chunk of code like this ... instead try and split your problem into smaller parts

start with a function to get the details of only one student

```
def get_student_detail(num_tests): # get the detail for just 1 student!
    student_name = input("Enter Student Name:")
    scores = []
    for i in range(1,num_tests+1):
        scores.append(float(input("Enter Score on test %s:"%i)))
    return {'name':student_name,'scores':scores,'avg':sum(scores)/float(num_tests)}
```

now just call this for each student

```
student_1 = get_student_detail(num_tests=3)
student_2 = get_student_detail(num_tests=3)
student_3 = get_student_detail(num_tests=3)

print("Student 1:",student_1)
print("Student 2:",student_2)
print("Student 3:",student_3)
```

or better yet implement a function that lets you keep going as long as you want

```
def get_students():
    resp="a"
    students = []
    while resp[0].lower() != "n":
        student = get_student_detail(num_tests=3)
        students.append(student)
        resp = input("Enter another students details?")
    return student
```

you may want to split out `get_student_details` even further writing a method to get a single test score and validate that its actually a number (this will crash as is if you enter something that isnt a number as a test score), or to keep asking for test scores until an empty response is given, etc

```
def get_number(prompt):
    while True:
         try: 
            return float(input(prompt))
         except ValueError:
            print ("That is not a valid number!")

def get_test_score(prompt):
    while True:
        score = get_number(prompt)
        if 0 <= score <= 100:
             return score
        print("Please enter a value between 1 and 100!")

test_score = get_test_score("Enter test score for test 1:")
print(test_score)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `validInput` back to `False` after the `while` loops or even better replace them to the beginning of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at the while-loops you have:

```
while not validInput1:
```

The first time that your application runs, `validInput1` is `False`, so this block evaluates. However, on subsequent loops (from `for i in range(3):`), `validInput1` is already true, so this block is entirely skipped.

You can fix this by changing `validInput1`, `validInput2` and `validInput3` to `False` at the beginning of your for-loop.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, I have implemented your suggestion and it worked. Is there any way you can suggest for me to get the highest score from all values stored in my totalScore array?

Answer (score 0):

That is because validInput1, validInput2 and validInput3 variables were set to True at first iteration but were not set to false for the second iteration.

Therefore for after first iteration your while conditions are always false due to "not True" i.e. False

Can set them to false again after each iteration i.e. at the end of the loop